# instalation of ubuntu touch in Defy plus, 'adb shell getprop ro.cm.device ' returned non-zero exit status 255

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I try to install ubuntu on a Motorola Defy plus, but I do not recognize the device, both in the facility or in the Device unlock.

```
[Licencing warning and precautions]

Do you accept? [yes|no] yes
error: device not found
ERROR:phablet-flash:Command 'adb shell getprop ro.cm.device ' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Comment: Did you start the service with "sudo adb start-server"?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ADB is not detecting the device...

You can try entering "fastboot mode" by turning the device off, holding Vol Up + Power, and then trying phablet-flash.

If this does not work, check your USB cable and research how to place your device into Fastboot mode.

---or---

Boot up your phone, enter Settings, enter "Development Menu", and enable ADB. I believe the installer uses Fastboot. If the above method fails, try this way. Also remember that you need your bootloader to be unlocked:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install